# How to change the font size of the dates for a Tableau Date Range Filter Slider?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using Tableau Creator and I implemented a simple text graph with a date range slide to represent the number of an item within a certain date range. I'm trying to get the text "12/1/2016" and "8/15/2019" larger, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that yet.

I've tried formatting the filter and modifying the font size on the Title and Body section. I've also went through each section of the Worksheet Format to see if I changed any of those font sizes if it will effect the size of this text. I've had no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to change the font size of the range readouts on the sides.